# Identity of the $p-$norm

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

A $p-$ norm of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a function $||_p: \mathbb{Q}_p \to \mathbb{R}$

$$x \neq 0, x=p^{w_p(x)}u \mapsto p^{-w_p(x)}$$

$$\text{ For } x=0 \Leftrightarrow w_p(x)=\infty \\ p^{-\infty}:=0$$

Identity:

- $\mathbb{Z}_p=\{ x \in \mathbb{Q}_p | |x|_p \leq 1 \}$

Could you help me to prove the above identity?

***EDIT:***

When $x \in Z_p$, it means that: $$x=a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+ \dots$$
$a_j \in \{0,1, \dots, p-1 \}$
$$$$
So that $x \in Q_p: x=\frac{r}{s}, r,s \in Z_p, s \neq 0 \Rightarrow x=\frac{b_0+b_1 p+b_2 p^2+ \dots}{c_0+c_1p+c_2p^2+ \dots}$

$$x=a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+ \dots=\frac{a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+ \dots}{1}$$

So, $x \in Q_p$.

Is it right so far? Also, how can I show that $|x|_p \leq 1$ ?

Comment: You don't have the right definition of $\Bbb Z_p$. You're thinking of the quotient ring $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ (and that symbol is indeed sometimes used for that quotient ring); but in this context, $\Bbb Z_p$ denotes the "$p$-adic integers" inside the completion of the rational numbers under the $p$-norm, or equivalently, expressions of the form $a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+\cdots$ where each $a_j\in\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$.

Comment: @GregMartin When $x \in Z_p$, it means that: $$x=a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+ \dots$$
$a_j \in \{0,1, \dots, p-1 \}$
$$$$
So that $x \in Q_p: x=\frac{r}{s}, r,s \in Z_p, s \neq 0 \Rightarrow x=\frac{b_0+b_1 p+b_2 p^2+ \dots}{c_0+c_1p+c_2p^2+ \dots}$

$$x=a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+ \dots=\frac{a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+ \dots}{1}$$

So, $x \in Q_p$.

Is it right so far? Also, how can I show that $|x|_p \leq 1$ ?

Comment: What is the definition of $w_p(x)$? What are its possible values when $x\in\Bbb Z_p$?

Comment: @GregMartin $$w_p(x):\left\{\begin{matrix}
Q_p \to \mathbb{Z} \cup \{\infty\}\\ 
p^mu \mapsto m\\ 
0 \mapsto \infty
\end{matrix}\right.$$